# Rails - Too much logic in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, view

I have an application used by several organizations and I want to check that users of one domain (a.domain.com) cannot edit users of another domain (b.domain.com). My question is where to put the logic, in a before filter or in the view?

View:

```
<% if @user.websites.detect {|website| website.url == request.host} %>
  render :partial => 'form'
<% else %>
  render :partial => 'no_access'
<% end %>
```

Or, in the controller:

```
before_filter :verify_editable_user, :only => ['edit', 'update', 'delete']
protected
def verify_editable_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id], :include => 'websites')
  unless @user.websites.detect {|website| website.url == request.host}
    render 'no_access'
  end
end
```

In this scenario, the first version feels cleaner to me. However, the second seems more along the MVC scenario. What do you think? Am I way off base? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the lockdown gem for authorization. (see http://stonean.com/)

The second one is in fact much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

A couple other authorization gems to check out would be [CanCan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and [acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't place logic in your views. Having logic in the controllers and not in the views will actually make your testing easier...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `before_filter` and [acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9).  Also using [presenters](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/simplifying-your-ruby-on-rails-code/) to get code out of your views and into a testable ruby object